# FireFox Specific CSS

Tags: css, firefox

background-color:transparent doesnt work on SELECTs in browsers other than FireFox.
So how I specify background-color:transparent for FF alone and background-color:#something for others ?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to apply the cross-browser setting first and the firefox specific setting afterwards?

```
select {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Find a simple example that is also working fine in Internet Explorer 8 and in Chrome 4 here: http://jsfiddle.net/b6hWu/

Comment: Tried. Works fine in FF & Opera showing transparency in FF & a specific background color in Opera.
But Chrome still shows some white+gray combination background.
Also tried @-moz-document url-prefix() { background-color:transparent;} which should render in FF only but no luck.

Comment: In chrome the option elements seem to translate transparent background-color to white background color. A good post about the inconsistent behavior can be found here: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-select-optgroup-options-css/

Answer (score 2):

Check out this page:

[CSS Browser selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/).

I use it and works wonders for selecting browsers right in the Stylesheet.

Hope it helps :)